# NotImplementedError: Type RObjectType.EXTPTR not implemented, when using rdata package in Python

Tags: python, file, rdata

I am trying to read an RData file in Python using the `rdata` package. I am using the following function:

`test = rdata.parser.parse_data("Input/my_file.RData")`

and I get the following error:

`NotImplementedError: Type RObjectType.EXTPTR not implemented`

Any help ? Did not find such an error on the web

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using this [package](https://pypi.org/project/rdata/?)?

Then you seem to be running into this [error](https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata/blob/release/0.8/rdata/parser/_parser.py#L652)

That means that the case for [EXTPTR](https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata/blob/4ee75165c29d4e87af0ec7555b6711b466bd253f/rdata/parser/_parser.py#L104) has not been implemented. It is probably best to report this as a feature request or bug to the developer.

It might help to also add the file you are using to this report.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using rdata. How I can report this bug to the developer ? Unfortunately I cannot share the RData because it is confidential

Comment: https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata/issues/new ?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the differences between these RData file mentioned here (https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata/blob/4ee75165c29d4e87af0ec7555b6711b466bd253f/rdata/parser/_parser.py#L104) ? I do not know why the type of my file is EXTPTR